# Is there a limit size of Spring RestTemplate postForObject?

Tags: spring, resttemplate

For example, if the post url is:

> http://www.wolf.com/pcap/search?stime={stime}&etime=${etime}&bpf=${bpf}

then can we do this:

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put("bpf", bpf);

...
responseString = restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, String.class,vars);
```

If bpf is a String, then is there a limitation of the size of bpf? Can it be any size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is: "It depends".

More precisely: as you append the `bpf` as a parameter to the URL it does not really matter if you are doing a POST or a GET. Sometimes there are restrictions on the length of an URL a server will handle, but that depends on what the server accepts, and cannot be determined from the RestTemplate, which is the client.

For example if the server you send the REST request to is a tomcat, then the maximal value of the complete header (URL, HTTP-Header etc) is by default 8kB for tomcat 6.0 or higher; see e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat

Just in case if you have control over the server side, too, you can change the expected interface by not sending the `bpf` as parameter, but as request body, like:

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
// vars.put("bpf", bpf); <--- not needed
responseString = restTemplate.postForObject(url, bpf, String.class, vars);
```

(and then of course get the `bpf` on the server from the request body instead).

Otherwise you are out of luck and have to limit the length of the URL. Maybe use a proxy or network sniffer to see what extra Headers are actually send and subtract that from the 8kB limit to get the maximal length of the URL.